# Content from a domain I used to own is appearing in my twitter feed

Tags: domains, wordpress, twitter

I had an old domain with a WordPress setup hosted by GoDaddy. I changed the business name and moved everything over to a new site, new domain, and new host a couple of years ago. I let the old domain expire.

It was recently purchased by someone for cheap, article spun content. Now, anytime they post a new article, it's automatically posted to my Twitter account. I contacted them to remove this, but given the quality of their spun articles, I doubt they will remove it.

Is there any recourse I have through Twitter or the host to get this removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you once set up a third-party service to automatically post the RSS feed for that domain to your twitter account. The old domain now has an active RSS feed again, and so the third-party service is posting to your account once more. You can revoke access to third-party apps by following these steps:

1. Log into your twitter account at https://twitter.com
2. Visit the verified apps page at https://twitter.com/settings/applications
3. Click "Revoke access" next to any apps you don't recognise or no longer have use for:
   [image: revoke access button]

This will prevent the previously authorised application from posting to twitter on your behalf.

It would also be a good idea to change your twitter password if you haven't already.